# What is the difference between a VIEW and a function that RETURNS TABLE?

Tags: sql-server, function, view

Views:

```
create view EMP as
select e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName from Employees e
```

Functions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EMP2() RETURNS TABLE as
RETURN (select e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName from Employees e)
```

Usage:

```
select * from EMP
select * from dbo.EMP2()
```

Is there any reason i should use one over the other? views just seem easier to use.

Comment: You can pass parameters to functions and use them in the function body

Comment: But wouldn't you be able to get the same behaviour with WHERE conditions? Also thanks for answering the post question.

Comment: In a simple case like this, yes.  But say, for example, you have a `CASE` in the query.  Then you could pass parameter values in and use the parameters in the `CASE`.  You would have to hardcode those values in a view.

Comment: A function can contain procedural code. You can use temp variables, loops, if-then-else etc. If you don't need these things, use views. They usually perform better than procedural code.

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate the clarity